# clicking on a link with specific part of known text- watir webdriver

Tags: hyperlink, click, webdriver, watir

I want to click on a link with variable text:

```
@variabletext = 'text' +@timestamp
```

But the link has a number like **01 # text010120121134**.  I just know text010120121134. Can someone help me click on the link with known text only.

Answer (score 5):

If you only know part of the link's text, use a regex to match the text:

```
browser.link(:text => /text010120121134/).click
```

This would match the link:

```
<a>01 # text010120121134</a>
```

Since the text "01 # text010120121134" matches the regex pattern "/text010120121134/". Note that regexes are denoted by the '/'s.